# Vnc Console with angular and python

Tags: python, angular, vnc

I would like to know if there is a way to connect angular 7 app to a windows or linux machine VNC using python on backend.

We want to have a page in out angular 7 app where we will fill vnc details and then can view the remote server as we view in case of tigerVNC or any VNC client

Answer (score 1):

I have used a python(flask) backend with angular a few times.

Plenty of examples on the internet of how to do so.

https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/

https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-integrating-flask-and-angularjs/

https://medium.com/@balramchavan/angular-python-flask-full-stack-demo-27192b8de1a3

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. We already have an app with python flask at backend and angular 7. Now we need to have vnc console there.

Comment: @PankajJarial Please checkout [noVNC](https://novnc.com/info.html). This is a VNC client JavaScript library